# Display text page inside mail body with Email-ext plugin in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, email-ext

I'm attaching a text file to the content of the email that is sent from jenkins, the thing is that the content of this file doesn't appear as it appear in any notepad, i've tried sending the email as plain text and as html but it still displaying the content in a diferent way.
For example if this is one of the lines in the file:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
                      MSP-B Automated Testing Report
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| scale-ive-0001-vertical-vpm2-160_prog_1_zone-check-acquire-time.py........OK |
```

This is how it looks like in the email:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
                      MSP-B Automated Testing Report
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| scale-ive-0001-vertical-vpm2-160_prog_1_zone-check-acquire-time.py....
| ....OK |
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For one of my Jenkins jobs I use the following together with HTML as overall email format,

```html
$PROJECT_NAME - Build # $BUILD_NUMBER - $BUILD_STATUS:

Check console output at $BUILD_URL to view the results.

<pre>
${FILE,path="Results.txt"}
</pre>
```

This way the email is formatted as HTML and the "[pre](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp)" tag instructs the mail client to not change the format of the included file.

Comment: It's working!
I want to run some script that is written in bash, before that email is sent, i have some log file that is the output of the build and my script will convert it to `HTML` format. Is there any option to run this script so the file that my Email will include is going to be the output of the script.

Comment: I would just add a build-step of type "shell script" and do the processing there

Answer (score 0):

Is this `....OK` a delayed output on the screen, i.e. first only the leading line shows up, then cursor waits, then the `OK` appears? It all depends on the content of the file, including hidden control characters.

If the above is true, it's possible the output had special control characters that can tell the OS to "go up a line, and start from position 'x'". So on screen (or in some editors) it will show correctly, but there is no way an email would understand that.

Without seeing the full actual content of the file (with line endings and control characters), it's difficult to say anything else.

Comment: The `...ok` is not delayed output , because it's a static text file which I'm only reading